# Beginner: FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] 'No such file or directory: C' on python vscode

Tags: python

I'm trying to put 2 csv files into a list in order to view them.

My path is correct. My files are in the path.

I get the error above, as if my editor doesn't recognize my C: drive. No matter how I set my path / put my csv files, Python doesn't recognize C: for some reason.

Any advice for a beginner who would like to get out the dealing with this type of minutia?

```
ls = []

path = r'C:\fMRI'


print(os.listdir(path))

li_mapper = map(lambda filename: pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0), path)

ls = list(li_mapper)

print(ls)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the [complete error](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/843953) you encounter.

Comment: debugging is a skill a beginner need to learn, simplify your program and analyze why things happen the way you don't want, relying on other people to find your bugs will very soon in ignoring you, it increases as your programs grow

Answer (score 1):

Strings are iterable. `C` is not a CSV file that can be read. In other words, `map(..., path)` will iterate `[C, :, \, ...]`

If you want to make a list of dataframes, then you want this.

```
path = r'C:\fMRI'

dfs = [ pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0) for filename in os.listdir(path)) ]
```

But you should also filter that `listdir` result on actual files that end in `.csv`.

Also, `pd.read_csv(filename`  is not the absolute path to the file, only the name. You will need to prepend the `path` variable to it.

Comment: This will only work if you are running this script from the location of the files

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work from anywhere you need to join the filename back with the path. I also argue this is getting a little long for list comprehension.

```
import os

path = r'C:\fMRI'
dfs = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.csv'):
        continue
    fpath = os.path.join(path,filename)
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(path, index_col=None, header=0))
```